# Create React App not installing, showing an error and aborting installation

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I Reinstalled Node.js and Yarn. Now I am getting this error.

My environment information is:

> Node: v8.12.0
>
> NPM: 6.4.1
>
> Yarn: 1.10.1
>
> OS: Windows 10

```
PS C:\Users\mdbel\Desktop\Project\redux> npx create-react-app learnredux

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\mdbel\Desktop\Project\redux\learnredux.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

yarn add v1.10.1
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@xtuc/long/-/long-4.2.1.tgz: Request failed \"404 Not Found\"".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "C:\\Users\\mdbel\\Desktop\\Project\\redux\\learnredux\\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Aborting installation.
  yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts --cwd C:\Users\mdbel\Desktop\Project\redux\learnredux has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting generated file... yarn.lock
Done.
```

Comment: remove `.npmrc` from `C:\Users\you\.npmrc` will solve this issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

removing `.npmrc` from `C:\Users\you\.npmrc` can also solve the problem.

Answer (score 30):

Once you have cleaned the yarn cache by running:

```
yarn cache clean
```

then subsequent calls to:

```
npx create-react-app your-app
```

will work.

Answer (score 28):

I had same issue and solved it by:

Installing latest version of node, npm and yarn.

`npm install -g npm@latest`
`nvm install node`
`npm install -g yarn`

nvm installs Node.js and npm manages packages.

Comment: This worked best for me. `npx create-react-app` was no problem anymore. Thanks!

Comment: This is the correct answer. `create-react-app` requires `Node >= 8.10 and npm >= 5.6`

Answer (score 9):

I solved this problem by deleting `.yarnrc` file from `C:\Users\yourUserName\`

Answer (score 5):

#### **I had a same problem then i tried the below Command and it fixed my issue**

```
npm cache clean --force
```

The above command didn't solved your problem then try the below one.

```
npm init -y
npx create-react-app your-app-name
```

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue when using `npx` and was able to resolve this with the following steps:

- Upgraded to latest yarn version: `$ npm i @yarn@latest`
- Remove node_modules folder
- Remove yarn.lock (if it exists).
- Remove .npmrc from your user folder.

If the issue still persist you can use yarn command instead : `$ yarn create react-app learnredux`

`yarn create` is available in Yarn 0.25+

Comment: removing `.npmrc` from `C:\Users\you\.npmrc` solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

updating to latest stable version of yarn and removing yarn cache folder in the AppData folder has solved my issue C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Yarn

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error on my Mac.

I just re-downloaded the installer from the Node.js website. This should reinstall all the dependencies and make sure that all paths are valid.

https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Answer (score 3):

This might help for Linux operating system

```
sudo npm install -g npm@latest
npm install node
npm init
npm install -g yarn
yarn cache clean
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Answer (score 2):

I also resolved my issue by installing the latest version of node from

https://nodejs.org/en/download/

And then i run below command

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

in the terminal
Followed by "create-react-app " or "create-react-app ." if you are already in the folder.

Answer (score 2):

Try this!

```
npm install -g npm@latest  

npm install node


npm install -g yarn


npx create-react-app appname

cd firstapp

yarn start
```

Answer (score 1):

Update node modules to version 13.12.0 that works for me

https://nodejs.org/es/download/current/

Comment: How would that help?

Answer (score 1):

Re-installing node to the latest version worked for me.

https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have the same issue and I am unable to solve but after uninstalling yarn and updating node with the latest version.

Also, make sure you have installed

```
npm i -g create-react-app
```

after updating the packages.

Clean the cache also to make it free from bugs this will definitely work

Answer (score 0):

Best method for windows user is update your yarn
If you use npx and got error than update yarn then use npx
I have same error in windows 8.1 then I updated yarn and it solved my problem

```
Npm I yarn@latest
npx creat-react-app  app name
```

Comment: Please try to use a code block for the runnable command lines or code in general

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. It seems that this occurs when `npm` and `node` installation is broken. However, sometimes clearing cache doesn't work. I had to not just uninstall but delete/purge all `npm` and `node` files on my system, and reinstall them back again.

**Remove node and npm**

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules
sudo rm -rf ~/.npm

sudo apt remove --purge npm
sudo apt remove --purge node
sudo apt remove --purge nodejs
```

Check if npm and node are removed by running: `which node` and `which npm`
If you still see some folders, try removing them using:

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
sudo apt-get remove npm
```

**Update system, just in case**

```
sudo apt-get update
```

**Install node and npm**

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo apt-get install npm
```

**Check installation**

```
npm -v
node -v
```

**Note:** The steps here involve removing existing modules and putting them back again. I also had to manually uninstall nodejs using **Programs and Features** (for Windows).

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally hid the `.yarnrc` file and that caused the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. Instead of yarn you can use npm to create the app. Just add the `--use-npm` flag so:

```
npx create-react-app app --use-npm
```