# Error : create-react-app Aborting installation

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

according to [Reactjs](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app) docs :

> You’ll need to have Node >= 8.10 and npm >= 5.6 on your machine. To create a project, run:
>
> npx create-react-app my-app

which my env meet it:

```
AymanMorsy@DESKTOP-6V4567D MINGW64 /g/reactprojects
$ node --version && npm --version 
v12.16.0 
6.13.4 

AymanMorsy@DESKTOP-6V4567D MINGW64 /g/reactprojects
$ npx create-react-app my-app
npx: installed 99 in 17.908s

Creating a new React app in G:\reactprojects\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/error-ex/-/error-ex-1.3.2.tgz
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'error-ex@^1.3.1' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'parse-json'
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AymanMorsy\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-12T21_29_30_123Z-debug.log

Aborting installation. 
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting my-app/ from G:\reactprojects
Done.
```

I tried solutions on  [Create React App not installing, showing an error and aborting installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52882119/create-react-app-not-installing-showing-an-error-and-aborting-installation#)

finally I formated C and installed latest update of windows10 and still see the same problem

**edite:** output of npm config list

```
$ npm config list
; cli configs
metrics-registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
scope = ""
user-agent = "npm/6.13.4 node/v12.16.0 win32 x64"

; builtin config undefined
prefix = "C:\\Users\\AymanMorsy\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"

; node bin location = C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
; cwd = G:\reactprojects
; HOME = C:\Users\AymanMorsy
; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.
```

Comment: What does `npm config list` output?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I added it in question now.

Comment: This might be an issue directly with npm https://status.npmjs.org/

Comment: I see `404 Errors with Certain Packages` when visiting this link :(

Comment: Indeed. This is why I posted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like https://registry.npmjs.org/error-ex is down for some regions

It will be soon up

Answer (score 0):

solution for this following ⤵
Install Scoop
and then install
yarn and then do `yarn create-react-app myapp`100% work definitely

Answer (score 0):

In my case, antivirus was stopping some of the modules from being accesses. Turned it off, also installed yarn. Works fine

1. Stop Antivirus momentarily.
2. npm install -g yarn
3. yarn global add create-react-app
4. npx create-react-app my-app
5. Start Antivirus

Although I feel that yarn is not mandatory to solve this issue in my case - I prefer yarn.
Hoping this helps someone out there.