# Getting trouble to create a new react app

Tags: reactjs, npm

While I'm Tring to create a new react app I'm getting an error message below,

> Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes. Installing
> react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...
>
> npm ERR! code ECONNRESET npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET npm ERR! network
> Invalid response body while trying to fetch
> https://registry.npmjs.org/jest-resolve: aborted npm ERR! network This
> is a problem related to network connectivity. npm ERR! network In most
> cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings. npm ERR!
> network npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure
> that the npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm
> help config'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\Akhlak Hossain
> Jim\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2020-11-17T06_20_31_124Z-debug.log
>
> Aborting installation.   npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel
> error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.
>
> Deleting generated file... package.json Deleting new-react/ from
> J:\learning_time_practices Done. npm ERR! code 1 npm ERR! path
> J:\learning_time_practices npm ERR! command failed npm ERR! command
> C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c ""create-react-app" "new-react"
> "--use-npm""
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\Akhlak Hossain
> Jim\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2020-11-17T06_20_31_497Z-debug.log

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you try first this one `npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/`? then try again to execute `npx create-react-app [your_app_name]`

Comment: Can you mark the answer as accepted so that other people will know that the answer did solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Not working bro...

Answer (score 1):

There May be a problem with automatic proxy setup, try this out

go to **settings> Network and Internet > Proxy**

and then under **Automatic proxy setup** turn off Automatically detect settings on Windows. And then open a command prompt and type the following command.

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Antivirus was the culprit which was blocking some files at the time of npx operation. [This helped my case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60197368/error-create-react-app-aborting-installation/65268201#65268201)

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command in case of mac

```
sudo chown -R 501:20 "/Users/username/.npm"
```

put username of your mac @username

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

try this one **npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/** it works for me and works for you and then create an app **npm create-react-app**

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35700885)