# npm ERR! code ECONNRESET when doing create-react-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, node-modules, create-react-app

I'm at my wits' end as I keep hitting this error when I'm trying to create-react-app. I am not using any proxies (like company proxy etc), as this is on my personal desktop.
[image]

When I check the logs, there is nothing.
[image]

I have tried the following solutions:

- tried using `npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/` (have also tried going to this site on the browser, and I am indeed able to access it)
- tried the following commands to remove proxy:`npm config rm proxy`, `npm config rm https-proxy`, `npm config delete proxy`, `npm config delete http-proxy`, `npm config delete https-proxy`
- tried `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` to update it
- tried `npm cache clean --force`
- installed yarn and used its create-react-app
- Uninstalled Node and reinstalled Node
- Updated to the latest version of npm
- Launched the command prompt in admin mode
- Disabled the "Automatically Detect Settings" in the Windows Proxy settings

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this thread help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64870344/getting-trouble-to-create-a-new-react-app --- I assume you tried rebooting? xD

Comment: Yes i have tried rebooting haha. I've also tried the top 2 solutions in that link, but regarding the last solution, I am on Windows Defender so I'm not sure if it applies.. might give it a shot though