# Create-react-app is not letting me create a react app, lots of error codes print out in terminal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, terminal, command-line

I am new to learning React and just finished a lesson in which the details of how to create a new app were laid out very simply but it is NOT working the way the lesson laid out. I get a whole load of errors that print out in the terminal. I included below what prints out in the terminal:

```sh
Lydias-Air:~ lydiapurves-ware$ npx create-react-app myfirstreactapp
Need to install the following packages:
create-react-app@5.0.1
Ok to proceed? (y) y

npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.

npm ERR! code EEXIST

npm ERR! syscall mkdir

npm ERR! path /Users/lydiapurves-ware/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/12/7c

npm ERR! errno -13

npm ERR! EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/lydiapurves-ware/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/12/7c'

npm ERR! File exists: /Users/lydiapurves-ware/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/12/7c

npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm

npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/lydiapurves-ware/.npm/_logs/2024-03-20T11_38_25_030Z-debug-0.log
```

I looked up some possible solutions and found a bunch of posts saying csrutil in Recovery Mode should fix it but it did not. I expected it would fix whatever permissions I don't have on my own computer but yeah, I still don't have certain permissions.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64870344/getting-trouble-to-create-a-new-react-app Try these solutions

Comment: CRA is no longer maintained or recommended. I'd suggest trying out [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/guide/#scaffolding-your-first-vite-project) instead

Comment: Looks like you've previously run `npm` commands using `sudo`. Don't do that. Remove the `~/.npm` directory and try again

Answer (score 1):

It appears there is an issue with your permissions.

```
npm ERR! EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/lydiapurves-ware/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/12/7c'
```

Have you tried running the command using sudo? Running npm command with sudo will create directories that can only be altered by the root user and lead to future npm commands throwing EACCESS: errors like the one your getting now.

Also, this block is asking you to remove a file from cache I believe.

```
npm ERR! File exists: /Users/lydiapurves-ware/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/12/7c

npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm

npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.
```

You could attempt to clear the cache using `npm clean cache --force`, or run your `npx create-react-app my_app --force` and npm will attempt to overwrite the file forcibly.

Comment: Had to do a bunch of permissions stuff and npm audit fixes, which put together with this advice fixed the problem! Thank you all for your help!