# Yarn Create - There appears to be trouble with the npm registry

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, yarnpkg

> ```
> $ yarn create react-app web --template typescript
> yarn create v1.22.5
> [1/4] Resolving packages...
> info There appears to be trouble with the npm registry (returned undefined). Retrying...
> info There appears to be trouble with the npm registry (returned undefined). Retrying...
> info There appears to be trouble with the npm registry (returned undefined). Retrying...
> info There appears to be trouble with the npm registry (returned undefined). Retrying...
> info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
> info There appears to be trouble with the npm registry (returned undefined). Retrying...
> [2/4] Fetching packages...
> error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/tmp/-/tmp-0.2.1.tgz: Request failed \"502 Bad Gateway\"".
> info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided 
>     in "C:\\Users\\Martins\\AppData\\Local\\Yarn\\Data\\global\\yarn-error.log".
> info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/create for documentation about this command.
> ```

**Windows: 10
Node: 14.11.0
Yarn: 1.22.5
npm: 6.14.8**

Comment: Do you have a `C:\Users\Martins\.npmrc` file? Try deleting that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create React App not installing, showing an error and aborting installation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52882119/4722345).

Answer (score 0):

If the problem continues to occur, you can try:

```
$ yarn init
```

And after

```
$ yarn create react-app web --template typescript
```

Check also if it is within the created directory of the project.